# Travis ci not picking up reference in c#

Tags: c#, travis-ci

When I am trying to build on Travis CI it keeps failing with error message "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2130,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference....." ([the build](https://travis-ci.com/tmathura/TorrentCreatorUploaderProject/builds/99741445))

I am using relative paths for my references so I am not sure why it is failing.

Comment: Looks like your nuget-packages are not restored or restored to the wrong directory

Comment: how do I fix that?

Comment: how did you configure nuget and which nuget version do you use ? the packages-folder seems to be in the wrong place

Comment: I am not sure if I am answeing your question correctly but I used the nuget manger. 

Name             : Package Manager Host

Version          : 4.9.3.5777

InstanceId       : 39053b2c-6550-41eb-a1ec-4f9d2d2f73d9

UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-ZA

CurrentUICulture : en-US

PrivateData      : NuGetConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.NuGetPSHost+Commander
DebuggerEnabled  : True

IsRunspacePushed : False

Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace